# Are these guard rails truly strong enough?

Tags: everyday-life, popular-science

I'm lay about physics, but I'd like to learn about it behind this question.

A friend criticises and claims that the single strip of traffic barriers (as shown below) would fail and is useless. For example, can it veritably protect and stop vehicles from falling off the bridge, especially provided that many double-decker buses and large trucks traverse them at speeds of around 100 km/hr.
Is she right? Yet what does physics reveal?

The left picture: [Ting Kau Bridge](https://www.google.com/maps/@22.362867,114.080401,3a,75y,109.42h,73.33t/data=!3m4!1e1!3m2!1s2WWaVuhEBWlI_QBta9eNGA!2e0). I purposely include a double-decker Citybus for reference.
The bottom picture: [Tsing Ma Bridge](https://www.google.com/maps/@22.352705,114.078825,3a,75y,270.73h,66.51t/data=!3m4!1e1!3m2!1sAa-ljuiTS5JrX3Qk6QXCUQ!2e0), depicted with a typical Hong Kong taxi.

[image]

Comment: what do you mean with useless?

Comment: @AntonioRagagnin I emended. Better?

Comment: What's her basis for claiming they won't work? Unless she's got intimate knowledge of the material strengths, anchoring methods, etc.,  ignore her as you would a claim that UFOs are causing cars to fall off bridges.

Comment: additionally cars and busses are moving in parallel to the railings - if the would hit the railing at a speed of 100km/h at an exact 90° angle they might break, but you're not able to accelerate that fast or drive around a such narrow turn at that speed. So not the whole impulse of the car is transferred. It's not easy to say, but at least in Europe there are standards for these kinds of railing with sufficient security margins - they won't fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hit one of these things at 100 km/hr after passing out at the wheel due to a medical issue.  It was between the road and a ravine.  I rode the guard rail for about 30 meters, and took out three of the vertical stanchions.  Airbags deployed.  Windows shattered.  Right side of the car ripped to shreds.   After coming to a stop, the cables were supporting the car at a 45 degree angle, keeping it out of the ravine.  Three people in the car; no one was even scratched.   (Quite a testimony to all the engineering:  seat belts, air bags, crumple zones ... and guard rails.  And also all the people who had less favorable outcomes which lead to the great engineering.)